# Dynamically stretch words to any screen height

Tags: javascript, html, svg

There is such a small program that dynamically changes a word inside svg. It is necessary to achieve such an effect that, regardless of the word or group of words, they are always stretched along the entire height (since they are rotated 90 degrees) by changing the font size (not changing the distance between the letters).

```js
let text = document.getElementById("text");
let input = document.getElementById("input");

function changeWord() {
    text.innerHTML = input.value;
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

svg {
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
}

input {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 12 75">
  <text id="text" transform="rotate(90 0 0)">Skibidi</text>
</svg>

<input value="Skibidi" oninput="changeWord()" id="input" type="text">
```

Comment: you must use SVG?

Comment: no, any way will do

Comment: i was thinking about `justify-content: space-between` but it will increase the space, and by the looks of thing, it's not what you want

Comment: you're right it won't do

Comment: must it be exact or it can be approximated?

Comment: in any possible way to increase the font of the word so that it stretches from 0 to 100% of the screen height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the font-size you can change the viewBox attribute so that the height of the viewBox is the same as the computed text length:

```js
let text = document.getElementById("text");
let input = document.getElementById("input");
let svg = document.querySelector("svg");
function changeWord() {
  text.innerHTML = input.value;
  svg.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", `-4 0 16 ${text.getComputedTextLength()}`);
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

svg {
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
  border:1px solid;
}

input {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-4 0 16 75">
  <g transform="rotate(90 0 0)">
  <text id="text">Skibpidi</text>
  </g>
</svg>

<input value="Skibidi" oninput="changeWord()" id="input" type="text">
```

Please observe that in order to allow space for descendants (p) I've changed the initial viewBox to `-4 0 16 75`

Comment: The question is off topic. Is it possible to make a word of one color and its last letter of another?

Comment: You will need to wrap each word in a `<tspan>` and give each tspan a different fill color. For this in the `changeWord` function you will need to split the `input.value` by empty space `" "`. If you need more help than this please ask it as a different question

Comment: @enxaneta  Thank you. An interesting and useful answer for me.

Comment: There's a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62958053/how-to-animate-changing-innerhtml