# How to animate changing innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

There's a little program, that dynamically stretches words to any screen height. It is based on innerHTML. How to make it fade in and out, when the word is changing?

```js
let text = document.getElementById("text");
let input = document.getElementById("input");
let svg = document.querySelector("svg");
function changeWord() {
  text.innerHTML = input.value;
  svg.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", `-4 0 16 ${text.getComputedTextLength()}`);
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

svg {
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
  border:1px solid;
}

input {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-4 0 16 75">
  <g transform="rotate(90 0 0)">
  <text id="text">Skibpidi</text>
  </g>
</svg>

<input value="Skibidi" oninput="changeWord()" id="input" type="text">
```

Comment: Setting an element's inner HTML is not an animatable process.

Comment: May it be possible to change this to some other method or property that can be animated?

Comment: You could create a new element at the same position, fade it in and fade the old one out. Or you could fade out, change the `innerHTML` and then fade in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am wrapping the added characters in a `<tspan>` element. The tspan is animated in css from `fill-opacity:0` to `fill-opacity:1` for a fade in effect. Please read the comments in the code.

```js
const SVG_NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

let text = document.getElementById("text");
let input = document.getElementById("input");
let svg = document.querySelector("svg");
let L; //the number of letters of the input value

function setWord() {
  let vals = input.value.trim().split(""); //trim for the empty spaces at the begining and the end of the string and split into an array
  L = vals.length; //the length of the array == the number of letters
  text.innerHTML = ""; //clear the content of the text element

  // set a variable for the text content
  let textcontent = "";
  vals.forEach((v) => {
    //add each value to the textcontent
    textcontent += v;
  });

  text.textContent = textcontent;
  //reset the viewBox value
  svg.setAttributeNS(
    null,
    "viewBox",
    `-4 0 16 ${text.getComputedTextLength()}`
  );
}

setWord();

function changeWord(e) {
  let vals = input.value.trim().split("");
  if (vals.length == L + 1) {
    // if the user is adding chars to the input
    //create a new element tspan to wrap the new character in
    let tspan = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, "tspan");
    //set the text content of the tspan element
    tspan.textContent = vals[vals.length - 1];
    //append the tspan to the text element
    text.appendChild(tspan);
    // reset the value of the L
    L += 1;
  } else {
    //if the user is deleting letters
    setWord();
  }
  //reset the viewBox value
  svg.setAttributeNS(
    null,
    "viewBox",
    `-4 0 16 ${text.getComputedTextLength()}`
  );
}

input.addEventListener("input", changeWord);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

svg {
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
  border:1px solid;
}

input {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

tspan{
fill-opacity:0;
animation: fo 2s forwards;
}


@keyframes fo{
  to{fill-opacity:1;}
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-4 0 16 75">
  <g transform="rotate(90 0 0)">
  <text id="text">Skibpidi</text>
  </g>
</svg>

<input value="Skibidi" id="input" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to use svg? Only you could do something along the lines of this:

```js
let text = document.getElementById("text");
let input = document.getElementById("input");

function changeWord(event) {
  let letter = document.createElement('div');
  letter.className = 'letter'

  // Handle delete key
  if (event.key === 'Backspace' && text.childElementCount > 0) {
    text.removeChild(text.lastChild);
  } else {
  // Assign last letter of the input to created div
    letter.innerHTML = input.value.slice(input.value.length - 1,
      input.value.length);
    text.appendChild(letter);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#text {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.letter {
  /* Allow spaces */
  white-space: break-spaces;
  transform: translateY(20px);
  animation: slide 1s forwards cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9);
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

input {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="text">
  <div class="letter">S</div>
  <div class="letter">k</div>
  <div class="letter">i</div>
  <div class="letter">b</div>
  <div class="letter">p</div>
  <div class="letter">i</div>
  <div class="letter">d</div>
  <div class="letter">i</div>
</div>

<input value="Skibidi" onkeyup="changeWord(event)" id="input" type="text">
```

Bearing in mind you'd have to style it how you want.

Comment: Not quite mister, unmatching letters when typing fast, 2x backspace to delete the inital letters.

Comment: You're right, well it's the best I can come up with, not sure what else to suggest

Comment: Don't tell me it's the best you can do, soldier! You can do better, it's just not the right time cuz it's friday.